# Page number at bottom edge with memoir?

Tags: memoir

I'm using the memoir class and the default page number location is the top edge of the page. How do I move it to the bottom edge?

Comment: Don't you just clear the default header and then add a page number to the footer?

Comment: @User23456234 Thanks. I didn't know what to look for. Created a custom header/footer that worked for everything except the first page of each chapter? I updated my question with what I'm seeing now.